# A problem with loading Marzipano viewer in Angular

Tags: angular, panoramas

I've been trying to integrate Marzipano in Angular and It looks like when I try to run it, it will only show a white page. I think the issue was that I was loading it in a component and it somehow got snag on init.

the ***index.html*** only contains this

```
</html>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

then I have a component, ***image.component.html***

```
<div id="pano" class="pano"></div>
```

then the typescript component: ***image.component.ts***

```
    ngOnInit() {
    this.loadPanorama(); // this will contain the marzipano load pano code
}
```